# Im creating a password generator and having some trouble on javascript

Tags: javascript, passwords

I am not sure how to get the event listener to work when I click the submit button and also when I check off and on the boxes in the check box. Can someone please take a look at my code and break things down using vanilla javascript I am completely new to this. Heres what I got thus far:

```
var lowercase = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
var uppercase = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
var numbers = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"];
var symbols = ["!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*"];
var passwordLength = document.getElementById("length");
var submitElt = document.getElementById("submit");
var textDisplayElt = document.getElementById("display");


submitElt.addEventListener("click",function () {

})




function generatePassword(passwordLength) {

   var password = "";
   for(var i = 0; i < passwordLength; ++i){
    var length = lowercase.length;
    var lowerLetters = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
    var lower = lowercase[lowerLetters];
    password = password + lower; 
   };

   for(var i = 0; i < passwordLength; ++i){
      var length = uppercase.length;
      var upperLetters = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
      var upper = uppercase[upperLetters];
      password = password + upper; 
     };

     for(var i = 0; i < passwordLength; ++i){
      var length = numbers.length;
      var randomNumbers = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
      var nums = numbers[randomNumbers];
      password = password + nums; 
     };

     for(var i = 0; i < passwordLength; ++i){
      var length = symbols.length;
      var symbolsGen = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
      var sym = symbols[symbolsGen];
      password = password + sym; 
     } 



   return password

}

var passwordLength = 20;
var password = generatePassword(passwordLength);
```

Comment: I've answered below, but please note that you don't have to put semicolons when you close a for loop

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
var lowercase = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
var uppercase = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
var numbers = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"];
var symbols = ["!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*"];

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var passwordLength = Number(document.getElementById("length").value.replace(/\D/g, ""));
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = generatePassword(passwordLength);
});

function generatePassword(passwordLength){
    var password = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++){
        var random = Math.random();

        if(random < .25){
            password += lowercase[Math.floor(Math.random() * lowercase.length)];
        }
        else if(random < .5){
            password += uppercase[Math.floor(Math.random() * uppercase.length)];
        }
        else if(random < .75){
            password += numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
        }
        else{
            password += symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length)];
        }
    }

    return password;
}
```

As long as your HTML elements look something like this:

```
<input type="number" id="length"/>
<button id="submit">Generate Password</button>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a fiddle a while back coz I was kinda tired for generating new keys each time for testing. Here is the path for that https://jsfiddle.net/vikasbhandari2/48bzhpmw/47/

Or, you can use this following clean trick to produce a random string. This is a very effective way of generating random strings and I use it heavily in prod.

```
(new Date().getTime() + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000)).toString(36)
```